Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement qiskit-ibm-runtime
after submitting pip install qiskit-ibm-runtime I get: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement qiskit-ibm-runtime
Please help,
thanks,
John

Please [edit] your question to include your Ubuntu version and pip version

pip 21.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip (python 3.6)

Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
